# DetailView with UUID getting NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

It was working with a normal `pk` but when I changed to UUID it stopped working.

Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_number = models.CharField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4().hex[:5].upper(), max_length=50, editable=False)
    product_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    order_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Pending')
    completion_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_number
```

url:
`path('panel/orders/<uuid:pk>', views.OrderDetail.as_view(), name='order-detail')`

template:
`<a href="{% url 'order-detail' o.pk %}" aria-current="page" class="dropdown-link w-inline-block w--current">`

Error:
`Reverse for 'order-detail' with arguments '('65830',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['panel/orders/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$']`

Comment: Your `order_number` uses `'65830'`, but that is not a valid uuid, since that has as pattern `[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}` so a total of 32 hexadecimal characters in groups of 8, 4, 4, 4 and 12.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is `default=uuid.uuid4().hex[:5].upper()` in my modelfield causing this?

Comment: likely yes. Moreover, it would not generate unique values, since it is evaluated once when you construct the class, and then uses the same value each time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 32 character UUIDs aren't really suitable for my use case as they're order numbers. What can I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.hex[:5].upper()`

from `default=uuid.uuid4().hex[:5].upper()`

`default=uuid.uuid4`

Answer (score 0):

UUID v4 has a certain format. If you want to use only 5 chars - it's not a uuid v4 anymore so you have to adjust your path accordingly.

Something like that should work.

```
re_path(r'^panel/orders/(?P<pk>[0-9A-Z]{5})$', views.OrderDetail.as_view(), name='order-detail')
```

But this only answers your question. You have another problem - your ids probably won't be very unique.